# zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available BUILD FAILED(Ubuntu 18.04 using python-build 20180424) EB CLI Installer

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, installation, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, command-line-interface

strong textSetting up AWS EB CLI Installer, on running  `./aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-setup/scripts/bundled_installer` while script was installing Python-3.7.2 throws error

```
 BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 18.04 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/python-build.20210401161307.18757
Results logged to /tmp/python-build.20210401161307.18757.log

Last 10 log lines:
    sys.exit(ensurepip._main())
  File "/tmp/python-build.20210401161307.18757/Python-3.7.2/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 204, in _main
    default_pip=args.default_pip,
  File "/tmp/python-build.20210401161307.18757/Python-3.7.2/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 117, in _bootstrap
    return _run_pip(args + [p[0] for p in _PROJECTS], additional_paths)
  File "/tmp/python-build.20210401161307.18757/Python-3.7.2/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 27, in _run_pip
    import pip._internal

zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available
Makefile:1130: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: ***[install] Error 1
  Exiting due to failure
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. You can just copy & paste the text from that terminal into your question, right? But I can't copy and paste it now, because you've turned it into a picture.

Comment: oh okay...but I copied and pasted the text from the terminal into my question(right above), adding the picture is to give more context to the question.

Comment: I mean, the crucial line was the `zipimport` one that you _didn't_ paste. The fact that zlib wasn't installed was your problem, and the reason your solution works, and it's not visible in your question except in a picture.

Comment: Okay, caught that...edit is done. thanks

Answer (score 1):

The command  `sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev` solved the issue, then proceeded to running `./aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-setup/scripts/bundled_installer` which worked fine.